# Return date from 32 bit hex

Tags: c, hex, decode

I have a binary file, which holds data from a data logger.

I have an extremely cryptic manual that helps the user decode the binary file, it gives an example:
The date “28/04/14 12:25:39” is coded in 32 bits: 0x3938C667

First, I entered this Hex string into a Hex to Dec converter and Hex to Ascii converter in hopes it would decode it to something close to a date. The hex string doesn't even have enough digits to equal the amount of digits of the date?

**Extra info:**

Here is some code also on the manual, doesn't give me much information...

The date / time are stored on 4 bytes and the structure is:

```
typedef union
{
     unsigned long val;
     struct
     {
          unsigned char seconds :6; // 00 - 59
          unsigned char minutes :6; // 00 - 59
          unsigned char hours :5; // 00 - 23
          unsigned char days :5; // 01 - 31
          unsigned char months :4; // 01 - 12
          unsigned char years :6; // 00 - 63
     };
}compact_date_t;
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the members of the `union` that you have defined?

Comment: Note that `unsigned long` is not necessarily 32 bits, and that bit-field locations and order are not specified by the C standard and are entirely not portable.

Comment: I hope this is just a toy example, because a year range of 00-63 is pretty useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitfield is giving you pretty much all of it.
Six lower bits for seconds. Let's take 6 lower bits - it would be

```
0x3938C667 & 0x3F = 0x27 = 39
```

** `0x3F` is `0000111111` in binary representation - masking out everything but the lower 6 bit.

Next the minutes - the next 6 bits:

```
(0x3938C667 >> 6) & 0x3F = 0x19 = 25
```

...
The rest you can work out yourself

Comment: thank you - I have little no working skills in C! A brief reading on bitwise opeators have me understanding your answer some. How do you know 0x3F is equal to 0000111111 or 111111? For 5 bits, would it be 11111 = 0x1F? For 4 bits, would 1111 = 0XF?

Comment: `&` is a bitwise `AND` operation, so it will effectively zero out the bits of the `0x3938C667 ` at the places `0x3F` has zeros, leaving only 6 lowermost bits.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the manual gives you exactly the information you need.  It is telling you that the first 6 bits are used for "seconds", the second 6 bits for "minutes", etc.  It is telling you the exact format of the date in binary.

If you add up all the bits, you get 32 bits, which is 4 bytes.

It's important to know that this is "right to left".  In other words the least significant 6 bits are "seconds" and the most significant 6 bits are "years".

Answer (score 0):

Forget about bitfields and use bit operations to extract and encode the date. Here you go:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/**
tm_sec  int seconds after the minute    0-61*
tm_min  int minutes after the hour  0-59
tm_hour int hours since midnight    0-23
tm_mday int day of the month    1-31
tm_mon  int months since January    0-11
tm_year int years since 1900
*/

struct tm bits_to_date(uint_least32_t i) {
    return (struct tm){
        .tm_sec =  (i >> 0u              ) & ((1u << 6u) - 1u),
        .tm_min =  (i >> 6u              ) & ((1u << 6u) - 1u),
        .tm_hour = (i >> (6u+6u)         ) & ((1u << 5u) - 1u),
        .tm_mday = (i >> (6u+6u+5u)      ) & ((1u << 5u) - 1u),
        .tm_mon = ((i >> (6u+6u+5u+5u)   ) & ((1u << 4u) - 1u)) - 1,
        .tm_year = (i >> (6u+6u+5u+5u+4u)) & ((1u << 6u) - 1u),
    };
}

uint_least32_t date_to_bits(struct tm t) {
    return 
        (uint_least32_t)t.tm_sec |
        (uint_least32_t)t.tm_min << 6 |
        (uint_least32_t)t.tm_hour << (6u+6u) |
        (uint_least32_t)t.tm_mday << (6u+6u+5u) |
        ((uint_least32_t)t.tm_mon + 1u) << (6u+6u+5u+5u) |
        (uint_least32_t)t.tm_year << (6u+6u+5u+5u+4u);
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const struct tm d = {
            .tm_sec = 39,
            .tm_min = 25,
            .tm_hour = 12,
            .tm_mday = 28,
            .tm_mon = 03,
            .tm_year = 14,
    };
    uint_least32_t v = 0x3938C667;
    fprintf(stderr, "%#lX\n", date_to_bits(d));
    struct tm r = bits_to_date(v);
    fprintf(stderr, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
        r.tm_mday, r.tm_mon+1, r.tm_year,
        r.tm_hour, r.tm_min, r.tm_sec
    );
    assert(date_to_bits(d) == 0x3938C667);
    assert(memcmp(&r, &d, sizeof(struct tm)) == 0);
}
```

The prorgam outputs:

```
0x3938C667
28/04/14 12:25:39
```